# How do connect this without ruining the topology

Tags: modeling, topology

I am almost finished making this character butt I can't seem to connect her head to the back of her head.
i have a picture right here
[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the below answer points you to specify *which* good topology you wish to preserve... if you need to animate the neck, you need to get good topology there, eg. There could be more solutions, depending on what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of how it will lead your loops, however to keep it all quads I can think of those connections:

[image: Proposal]